# Where is "Zaouiate Oued Ifrane"?

Tags: identify-this, morocco

There is a Wikivoyage article about [Zaouiate Oued Ifrane](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Zaouiate_Oued_Ifrane) that says:

> Better known as Zaouia d'Ifrane, or even Ifrane if you are within the village limits, this Berber village is often confused for another town in the mid-Atlas with the name Zaouia d'Ifrane, and many times it is even confused for the larger city of Ifrane proper itself.

Anyone know the coordinates of this place?

Note that this article has been written by just one single-purpose user, which usually is synonym with biased, not-peer-reviewed information. It might even be pure invention. Anyway, I would appreciate any information identifying this place.

Google Maps has no notion of it.
Discussion with some confusion around this name: http://www.lonelyplanet.com/thorntree/thread.jspa?threadID=2200744

Similarly-named places:

- [Zaouia d'Ifrane](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zaouia_d%27Ifrane)
- [Ifrane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ifrane)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe it'd be at [33.1962N, 5.4201W](https://www.google.com/maps?q=M%27Rirt,%20Mekn%C3%A8s-Tafilalet,%20Morocco&hl=en&ie=UTF8&ll=33.19555,-5.419629&spn=0.007541,0.013937&sll=23.241346,-20.214844&sspn=114.00171,228.339844&oq=Mrirt&hnear=M%27Rirt,%20Khenifra%20Province,%20Meknes-Tafilalet,%20Morocco&t=m&z=17) on Google Maps.

I found it by following the directions on [Wikitravel to Zaouiate Oued Ifrane](http://wikitravel.org/en/Zaouiate_Oued_Ifrane):

> Zaouiate Oued Ifrane is located about 100K south of Fez. The road
>   which dead ends at Zaouiate Oued Ifrane turns off from the main
>   roadway after the town of Souk L'Hdd and before the city of Mrirt.
>   Transportation to and from Zaouiate Oued Ifrane is the only deterrent
>   to visiting, if there is one. By personal car/vehicle it is no
>   problem, just head south from Fez toward Azrou, at Azrou, continue on
>   as if going to Marrakesh and then take the left directly after Souk
>   L'Hdd.

On google maps there's not much civilisation there, but there is a road that ends at the Cascades.  Wiki mentions

> there is a great swimming hole up the river where one can relax on
>   large rocks in the sun and take dips into the cold spring fed river at
>   their leisure. Or if you crave something a bit colder and more
>   adventurous, take a shower under the 100 foot waterfall.

which seems to match this.  Satellite view confirms that there is a town there.

I then looked it up on OpenStreetMap and [confirmed that they also show a location](http://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=15/33.1949/-5.4225) by this name which matches these directions.

Comment: (I love questions like this)